# Internet is connected but connection alert keeps popping up

Tags: internet

I previously surfed the internet and went into a site that has a collection of tv series so you can watch it online, but then my mac started beeping and telling me to download mackeeper due to a virus. This happened once before, so i didn't bother downloading it again since i had it, and nothing happened after. Now my mac keeps putting pop ups that says:

"**Connection alert** We are having troubles. Download Hotspot Shield t..." 
I can't get the pop up to show more. If i click the pop up, hotspot shield .exe is downloaded and does not open when finished. 
My internet works fine, but the pop up keeps appearing a few minutes and covers a side of my screen. What can I do?

*I use macos sierra version 10.12.6 and google chrome*

*Oh and google chrome and kakaotalk(korean messenger app) works fine, but i can't seem to open some apps such as skype and parallels desktop due to no internet connection*

[image: Scs of popup]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/305438/edit) your question to include what version of macOS you're running and which browser(s) you use? Also, have you checked to see if this only happens with one browser, or multiple browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you had once installed MacKeeper on your mac so this resulted in installing a ton of Malware's on your Mac but don't worry you can easily get rid of all those Malware's

Download this Malware Cleaning Software https://www.malwarebytes.com it is a very popular malware cleaning software for effectively cleaning malware and it is even recommend by Apple (an Apple senior advisor over Apple chat support suggested this software to me! )

Until and unless you clean the malware from your mac those messages will keep popping no matter which website you visit cause it is installed on your mac not on the web in your case

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. i downloaded the software you recommended and ran it fully until it said there was nothing harmful left on the computer (I had to manually delete some folders myself because some adwares had no remedies? but anyways after that the malwarebytes said my mac was clean). But the pop up still comes up??

Comment: @jinellie Upload a screenshot of the Pop Up!

Comment: @jinellie Don't worry anymore you are now free of malware the pop ups which are already after the clean up might be occasional add pop pups to disable it completely go to so extension gallery and install am about extinsion it will not only block annoying as but also the pop ups you are seeing

Comment: I just uploaded a picture of the popup! And could you give me the exact name of the extension? I can't seem to find what you're recommending on the google extension store

Comment: @jinellieGo to this link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom and download it (Adblcok Extension) from the chrome web store

Comment: @jinellie And are you using your iPhone's hotspot or is your iPhone somehow connected with your mac?

Comment: I already have adblock running, updated my computer, but the pop up just seems to appear repeatedly. And no, I don't use an iPhone - I use a samsung phone. btw, the I found out the full pop up says "Connection Alert. We are having troubles. Download Hotspot shield to get secure and unrestricted access"

Comment: @jinellie Download App Cleaner from freemacsoft then completely uninstall chrome then uninstall chrome using it then hold option on your keyboard and click Go in the finder menu bar then the window which appears search for Google folder and delete and first of all upload a screenshot of all the apps you have on your mac and also all the chrome extensions you have!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like a scam to me - *"oops, we think you've got a problem - download our problem fixer to fix it."*
The 'problem fixer' is malware/adware or at best a PUP [potentially unwanted program].

Fortunately, as you're on a Mac, their dumb scam app won't run - so you got away with it this time.

Pick better sites to visit in future.

MacKeeper is marketed in the same way - there's plenty of discussion online as to whether that's actually malware or just the worst marketing campaign ever.